# Returning class pointer, when asked for struct pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I have a skeleton of a project I need to implement a Doubly Linked List (no using stl) and the way the class is implemented is to inherit all is methods from a struct like so:

```
struct IDoubleList { 
virtual IDoubleNode * getHead() = 0;
virtual IDoubleNode * getTail() = 0;
virtual void setHead(IDoubleNode * head) = 0;
virtual void setTail(IDoubleNode * tail) = 0;
virtual void addBack(int value) = 0;
};

class DoubleList : public IDoubleList {
public:
virtual IDoubleNode * getHead();
virtual IDoubleNode * getTail();
virtual void addBack(int value);
virtual void setHead(IDoubleNode * head);
virtual void setTail(IDoubleNode * tail);
private:
DoubleNode* m_Head;
DoubleNode* m_Tail;
};
```

As you can getters and setters use the struct, not the class to return/pass pointers. My question is how can I use the methods in he object m_Tail is pointing to. I tried using m_Tail.setNext(newNode); where setNext is method in the DoubleNode class but that says the expression must have a class type.

Also when I return/pass a DoubleNode* should I be casting or something to IDoubleNode*? or maybe its the other way around?

PS been a while since ive used C/C++, maybe I'm forgetting something about function pointers? idk so lost right now

Thanks in advanced, let me know if you need any more info

Comment: There is no such thing as a distinction between class pointers and struct pointers. (That wouldn't seem to answer your question, but it should be commented to the headline).

Comment: Why have you defined an interface for which there is a single implementation? The question is a bit rethorical, if there is only one implementation, creating an interface (pure abstract class) will add complexity and offer no benefit. Reconsider your design.

Comment: read my post, i have the skeleton i can only implement classes given to me nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be `m_Tail->setNext(newNode)`, not `m_Tail.setNext(newNode)` because `m_Tail` is a pointer. You could also do `(*m_Tail).setNext(newNode)`, the point is that you have to dereference the pointer somehow.

No, you do not need to cast a pointer from a `DoubleList` to `IDoubleList` when passing it to a function expecting an `IDoubleList`. This is because *every* `DoubleList` *is a* `IDoubleList`, so no casting is required. Also, the *only* difference between a `struct` and a `class` is the default access level of the members (`public` for a `struct`, `private` for a `class`).

Comment: thanks a lot, i knew there was definitely a way to use a dot operator. for some reason using -> was giving me a error:expression must have pointer-to-class type

Comment: @AnkurVashi `->` operator can only be with pointers pointing to an object. For example, `foo obj;`, `obj` is not pointer to an object of type `foo` but the object itself. So, you have to use `.` operator to access its members.

Comment: I think you were doing something wrong with your syntax somewhere; if `(*a).b()` works, then `a->b()` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make `IDoubleNode` a base class of your `DoubleNode` (if you haven't already). Then you need to `dynamic_cast<DoubleNode*>(ptr)` in the methods taking a `IDoubleNode*` to get hold of your `DoubleNode` (and e.g. throw an exception if this fails). Also, make sure you use pointer notation when accessing members of pointers, i.e. `ptr->member` instead of `ptr.member`: the latter notation only works for objects. You could use `(*ptr).member` but this is unnecessarily contrived.

Finally, don't forget to tell your instructor to set reasonable assignments next time because this is an entirely pointless exercise: this is bad example for using object oriented approaches (you can subvert type-safety via the base class interface) and it is pointless to use object oriented approaches in a data structures class.